# Windows Sound bug

Tags: windows, windows-8, audio, sound-card

I got some issue with Windows 8, some time when I connect my Stereo casque or I disconnect it my the sound stop working, I got this litle red x on the sound icons, so each time I had to restart my pc.

Comment: What's a casque?

Comment: Headphones by Dr Dre probably...

Comment: no it's simple headphones.

Answer (score 0):

Some sound systems used in PCs detects when headphones, speakers or microphones are detected and then pops up a dialog to make sure you have connected the correct type of device to a matching port on the computer. This is handled by the sound driver and related application. The error occuring when connecting / disconnecting suggests that something makes the driver crash when the device change is detected.
I would first try to resolve the problem by installing the latest audio drivers for Windows 8 from your system manufacturers website.

Comment: I have Installed last Driver But Always got the same problem.